# How to pass arguments to on-download-complete script

Tags: aria2

I have a couple of commands to execute once a download via aria is complete...

I followed the doc and I have the following line in my script:

```
mail="some mail passed from another script"
urls="link1 link2..."
aria2c --on-download-complete "$(pwd)/ariahook.sh" -Z $urls
```

ariahook.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Called with [$1] [$2] [$3] [$4] [$5]"

# use mutt to send email...
```

Basically the $1, $2 $3 are already passed by aria to my script, I would love to pass a 4th one containing the email address so I can send an email notification via mutt in my ariahook script.

is there anyway to achieve this?

(or an alternative way to get notified even if it does not use on-download-complete)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Aria2c doesn't let you provide an argument, so ariahook.sh has to get the email-address by it self:

**ariahook.sh** can look like that:

```
myEmailAddress=user206904@gmail.com
pathToCompletedDownload="$3"
echo "$pathToCompletedDownload" | mutt $myEmailAddress -s "download complete"
```

And you will receive an email every time a download completed.